# How to initialize a value to a object decleared in a vector?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, initialization, stdvector

Well, my question is how can I set a value to the object `cood` of class `coordinates` created in a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class coordinates
{
public:
    short int x;
    short int y;
};

int main()
{
    vector<coordinates> cood[1];
    cood[1].x=(short int)4;
    cood[1].y=(short int)5;

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error

```
class std::vector<coordinates>' has no member named 'y'.    
(for both x and y).
```

I have tried different methods but always get some error.

Comment: `vector<coordinates> cood = { {4, 5} };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
vector<coordinates> cood[1];
```

means an array of `vector<coordinates>` contains one `vector<coordinates>`. The `cood[1]` is also wrong, because the array indexing starts from `0, 1,..., n-1`, not `1, 2,..., n`. Accessing the out of bound will leads to [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Access_out_of_bounds), hence the posted code has a UB.

You should have `cood[0]` instead, which means, the first element of the `cood` array(i.e. of type `vector<coordinates>`). Obviously the `vector<coordinates>` has no member `x` and `y`, hence you will get compiler error.

---

You probably mean to do

```
vector<coordinates> cood(1);
```

which is a *vector of coordinates* with one `coordinates` element, that will be default initialized by the default-constructor generated by the compiler.

But, you can do directly *[brace-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)* for the trivial types like:

```
std::vector<coordinates> cood{ {4, 5} };
```

which does the same as you meant to do.

Comment: Thanks, I found the error. It was "vector<coordinates> cood[1]; " .

Comment: @Cruz Yeap. **undefined behaviour**! See the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw when I refreshed. Thank you.